# keep column name variable in Java INSERT INTO command with PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

I have the following problem:
I have two tables in one data base which consist of the same columns besides the name of the last column. I want to write data into them using Java.
I want to use the same preparedStatement for both tables, where I check with an if-command whether it is `table`1 or `table`2. `table`2 has `amount10` as the name for the last column, `table`1 has `amount20` for it. This `number` is stored in a variable within my code.

Below you can see a (simplified) example and how I tried to let the column name variable but it doesn't work. Is there any way to fix this without copying the whole statement and manually changing the `number` variable?

```
String insertData = "INSERT INTO `database`.`"+table+"`
(`person_id`,`Date`,`amount`+"number") VALUES "+
"(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
"`person_id` = ? , " +
"`Date` = ? , " +
"`amount`+"number" = ? ; ";
PreparedStatement insertDataStmt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work since variables number and table are not going to be magically injected into your insertData string while you are changing them.
I'd to a method prepareInsertstatement(String table, String number) that would return correct PreparedStatement:

```
public void prepareInsertStatement(Connection conn, Strint table, String number) {
    String insertData = "INSERT INTO `database`.`"+table+"`
    (`person_id`,`Date`,`amount+"number"') VALUES "+
    "(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
    "`person_id` = ? , " +
    "`Date` = ? , " +
    "`amount+"number"' = ? ; ";
    PreparedStatement insertDataStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertData);

    return insertDataStmt;
}
```

Just remember to close the PreparesStatement when you don't need it any more.

Comment: Cool, this worked!!! Thank you so much and sorry for not posting the error that has been shown!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that reason for that is invalid syntax. When you concatenate string for last column name you use code `'amount' + number`. If your number value is 20, than concat result will be
`'amount'20` that cause invalid syntax exception. Just move one extra `'` after number.

`"'amount" + number + "'"`

Note: log, or just error that appears during this statement execution would be very useful to find right answer for your question.